# Is it more tax efficient to use a website that does the logistics, manufacturing and selling for you?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, small-business, income

Is it more tax efficient to use a website that does the logistics, manufacturing and selling for you like Merch By Amazon, or is it more tax efficient to create your own store with Shopify, do your own logistics and set up relations with manufacturers by yourself.

I am thinking while the profits might be higher in the later, I will have to file more tax documents in doing so and spend more in taxes, not to mention the higher upkeep cost and just the cost of doing business. I don't think there's any hidden cost with solutions like Mech By Amazon, or is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using websites for your business doesn’t have any impact on the taxes you owe. Also, nothing is for free, so in the end you pay for their use somehow somewhere, and end with less profit.